# Unable to display image from Sqlite to wpf window

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

i am trying insert image as blob in Sqlite and trying to retrieve the same to display in Table control by creating row dynamically.

i could able to do all the steps, inserting to the Sqlite, retrieving and then creating image, tablecell and tablerow respectively. But somewhere it is going wrong, Image is not getting displayed on the final window.

My workouts:

Inserting:-

```
    
    string aQuery = "INSERT INTO images (FileType,OrgFile) VALUES ('JPEG','@image')";
    SQLiteParameter AddParameter = new SQLiteParameter("@image", System.Data.DbType.Binary);
    AddParameter.Value = File.ReadAllBytes("C://sample.jpg");
    SQLiteCommand SqliteCommand = new SQLiteCommand(aQuery, SqliteCon);
    SqliteCommand.Parameters.Add(AddParameter);
    SqliteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Retrieving:-

```
    
    BitmapImage BImg = new BitmapImage();
    Image Img = new Image();
    SQLiteCommand SqliteCommand = new SQLiteCommand("select OrgFile from user_images where UserID=1",               SqliteCon);
    SQLiteDataReader myDataReader = SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader();
    while (myDataReader.Read())
    ResultBytes = GetBytes(myDataReader);
    using (MemoryStream ImgMs = new MemoryStream(ResultBytes))
    {
        BImg.BeginInit();
        BImg.StreamSource = ImgMs;
        BImg.StreamSource.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        BImg.EndInit();

        Img.Source = BImg;
        Img.Width = 1000;
        Img.Height = 1000;
    }
```

Adding to Table:-

```
    
    TableRow TableRow = new TableRow();
    InlineUIContainer ImgUICont = new InlineUIContainer(Img);
    Paragraph Paragraph = new Paragraph(ImgUICont);
    TableCell TableCell = new TableCell(Paragraph);
    TableCell.Style = (Style)TryFindResource("TableDataCell");
    TableRow.Cells.Add(TableCell);
    UsersTable.Rows.Add(TableRow);
```

Please help, if anybody could find the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Because you close the image stream right after EndInit, you need to set `BImg.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;`. See the [Remarks section here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.cacheoption.aspx) for details.

Comment: Hi Clemens, thanks for your help. Its working now. But i think, i cant mark your as correct answer because you answered as commnet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.cacheoption.aspx):

> Set the CacheOption to BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad if you wish to close a
>   stream used to create the BitmapImage. ...

So your code should look like this:

```
using (MemoryStream ImgMs = new MemoryStream(ResultBytes))
{
    BImg.BeginInit();
    BImg.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    BImg.StreamSource = ImgMs;
    BImg.EndInit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
ResultBytes = GetBytes(myDataReader);
```

to

```
ResultBytes = GetBytes(myDataReader[0]);
```